# how to match arabic word with "tashkel"?

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic

i'm using the following function to highlight certain word  and it works fine in english

```
function highlight(str,toBeHighlightedWord)
     {

        toBeHighlightedWord="(\\b"+ toBeHighlightedWord.replace(/([{}()[\]\\.?*+^$|=!:~-])/g, "\\$1")+ "\\b)";
        var r = new RegExp(toBeHighlightedWord,"igm");
        str = str.replace(/(>[^<]+<)/igm,function(a){
            return a.replace(r,"<span color='red' class='hl'>$1</span>");
        });
        return str;
     }
```

but it dose not for Arabic text

so how to modify the regex to match Arabic words also Arabic words with tashkel, where tashkel is a characters added between the original characters 
example:
"محمد" this without tashkel
"مُحَمَّدُ" with tashkel 
the tashkel the decoration of the word and these little marks are characters

Comment: You might consider http://xregexp.com/ / https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp for an advanced JS regex engine that can deal with Unicode, among many other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript, you can use the word boundary `\b` only with these characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. A lookbehind assertion can not be useful too here since this feature is not supported by Javascript.

The way to solve the problem and "emulate" a kind of word boundary is to use a negated character class with the characters you want to highlight *(since it is a negated character class, it will match characters that can't be part of the word.)* in a capturing group for the left boundary. For the right a negative lookahead will be much simple.

```
toBeHighlightedWord="([^\\w\\u0600-\\u06FF\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70-\\uFEFF]|^)("
              + toBeHighlightedWord.replace(/([{}()[\]\\.?*+^$|=!:~-])/g, "\\$1")
              + ")(?![\\w\\u0600-\\u06FF\\uFB50-\\uFDFF\\uFE70-\\uFEFF])";
var r = new RegExp(toBeHighlightedWord, "ig");
str = str.replace(/(>[^<]+<)/g, function(a){
    return a.replace(r, "$1<span color='red' class='hl'>$2</span>");
}
```

Character ranges that are used here come from three blocks of the unicode table:

- [0600-06FF](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=12) *(Arabic)*
- [FB50-FDFF](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/FB50-FDFF) *(Arabic Presentation Forms-A)*
- [FE70-FEFF](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/FE70-FEFF) *(Arabic Presentation Forms-B)*

Note that the use of a new capturing group changes the replacement pattern.

Comment: Is there any working example for the above function or how to implement this function to replace arabic words wrapped in side a div tag

Comment: how can i make it work with following example http://jsfiddle.net/u3k01bfw/13/, in my case it doesnt match all keywords